# Design review: Spring JPA entity versioning with "version switching"

Tags: java, spring, jpa, versioning

I'm writing backend for a cms of sorts that needs to support having different versions of its entities and also the ability to choose which of the versions is the current/active one. I've looked around on this site and others and found some advice on implementing versioning (which I've taken to heart) but nothing in terms of "version switching", as I call it.

My question is twofold, I suppose:

1) I want to know if there is any (preferably open-sourced) system that does something similar? Are there any design patterns that are related to what I'm doing?

2) I would appreciate a review of my implementation below.

Here's a rundown of my entities:

Firm:

```
@Entity
public class Firm {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "firm_firm_version")
    private FirmVersion firm;
```

FirmVersion:

```
@Entity
public class FirmVersion {

    @EmbeddedId private FirmVersionId id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "firmVersion")
    private List<Staff> staff = new ArrayList<>();
```

FirmVersionId:

```
@Embeddable
public class FirmVersionId implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private Integer version;
}
```

FirmStaff:

```
@Entity
public class FirmStaff {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<FirmVersion> firmVersion = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;
    // ...fields
}
```

This works fine, but my main concern is the propagation of these @ManyToMany relations. The way I implemented it, every time you update a staff you create 1) a new staff and 2) a new FirmVersion and however many table rows it takes to link them, which I imagine can get out of hand pretty quickly.